# Is there a way to wholesale rewrite all the metadata from gdal.GetProjection() back into a raster?

Tags: gdal

I am using gdal (Python) to get metadata out of a geo tiff using GetProjection.  I do some manipulation on the raster in openCv, and i would like to then re-merge the altered raster data with the meta data string that is returned by GetProjection.  I have been able to individually set parameters with specific methods from osr, but it requires me to parse the long string I get from GetProjection and then find the corresponding setter from osr.  Is there some way to do this all in one fell swoop?

here is my reader function --

```
def read_ortho4align(filename):
    # open ortho in gdal to get affine transform from pixels to geo space
    imgeo = gdal.Open(filename)
    xfrm = imgeo.GetGeoTransform()
    geoinfo = imgeo.GetProjection()
    print("xfrm for image = ", xfrm)
    imgeo = None #free-up memory
    # open ortho (again) with opencv for image content manip  
    img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL) #I think this is where big file reading is failing
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edgemask = make_edge_mask(imgGray)
    return img, imgGray, edgemask, xfrm, geoinfo
```

And here is where I re-constitute my geotiff (snippet)

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, bands, gdal.GDT_Byte, options = ['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF',])
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(32615)  #TODO - fix hardcoded 
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
```

Comment: If Projection not changed during raster manipulation, why not to set it back to output raster? geoinfo = imgeo.GetProjection() and outRaster.SetProjection(geoinfo)

Comment: I will try that.  Wow, how did I miss that?  I will be back later to mark as answer if that works.